# how to evaluate this multivalue expression $(e^i)^i$?

Tags: complex-numbers

from definition:$(e^i)^i=e^{i\cdot log {(e^i)}}=e^{i\cdot log {(e^i)+2k\pi i}}=e^{i\cdot ( {log {(e^i)+2k\pi}})}=e^{i\cdot ( {i+2k\pi})}=e^{-1 +2k\pi i}=e^{-1}$... it turned out to be single value, I think there should be something wrong here, anyone can point out, thanks!

Comment: Why do you think it's multivalued? There is nothing multiple-valued about the exponential function, only the logarithm has that feature.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $(e^i)^i$ is of the form $z^w$ for complex numbers $z$ and $w$ which requires the complex logarithm for evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Power Rule for complex exponents 
$$
\begin{align}
(e^i)^i&= e^{(i+2n\pi i)i}\text{ for }n\text{ in }\Bbb{Z} \\
&= e^{-1-2n\pi}
\end{align}$$

Working from your chain of equalities $$
(e^i)^i=e^{i\cdot \log {(e^i)}}=e^{i\cdot(i \arg(e^i)+2k\pi i)}=e^{i\cdot(i+2k\pi i)}=e^{-1-2k\pi}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The `log` in $\log(e^i)$ should be the [*complex* logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm). So you should *not* write $\log(e^i)=i$.